# If a subset of metric space $(X,d)$ like $S$ is closed and bounded, does it imply that $X$ is totally bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $S$ be a subset of $X$. If $S$ is closed and bounded, does it imply that $X$ is totally bounded?

Comment: Obviously not.  Are you really asking the Question that you meant to ask?  If $S$ consists of a single point in $X$, regardless of what metric space $(X,d)$ actually is, then $S$ is closed and bounded.  Why would this imply anything about $X$ being bounded?

Answer (score 2):

Take $l_\infty$ and $S = \{e_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$. The $S$ is closed, bounded, but not totally bounded since $\|e_i - e_j\| = 1$ for all $i \neq j$
(hence there can be no finite $\epsilon$-net for $\epsilon <1$).

Comment: More simply, just take any infinite set with the discrete metric.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I often feel that the discrete metric is cheating :-).

Answer (score 1):

Essentially the same example as given by copper.hat, but perhaps written in a simpler way.

Let $X=\mathbb{N}$ and let $d$ be the discrete metric given by $d(m,n)=1$ if $m\neq n$ and $d(m,n)=0$ if $m=n$. Every subset is closed and bounded by $1$. But only finite subsets admit an $1/4$-net.